# Understanding condition based joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Well, I ended up with a 1000 line stored procedure that I have to modify, in my current project. It is currently using obsolete operators, which I have to replace with proper joins. It looks like this:

```
SELECT
     PRDE_Parts_Spec_ID
    ,PRDE_Service_Center_ID 
    ,ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(PRDE_Qty_Required,0)),0) - ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(PITM_Total_Qty_Received,0)),0)
FROM 
    TBL_Purchase_Request_Details 
    Inner Join 
    TBL_Purchase_Request_Master 
    ON PRMA_Purchase_Request_No = PRDE_Purchase_Request_No 
    Left Join 
    TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master 
    ON ( PRDE_Parts_Spec_ID = PITM_Parts_Spec_ID AND 
         PRDE_Service_Center_ID = PITM_Service_Center_ID AND 
         PRDE_Required_Delivery_Date = PITM_Expected_Arrival_Date 
    )
WHERE
    PITM_Related_Request_Type_Id = 82 
    AND PRMA_PR_Status_ID IN (41,146,213,9097) --PO Raised,Received,Invoiced,Partially received statuses
    AND PRMA_Supplier_ID = 0
    AND PRMA_Order_Date < @dtEndDate    
    --and (
    --(PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID != 145 AND PRMA_Purchase_Request_No *= PITM_Related_Request_No)
    --OR ( PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145 AND PRDE_MR_No *= PITM_Related_Request_No) 
    --)
    and not exists
    (SELECT POTM_Related_Txn_No 
    FROM TBL_Parts_Out_Txn_Master
    WHERE POTM_Related_Txn_No = PITM_Parts_In_Request_ID
    and POTM_Destination_Details = PITM_Source_Details
    and POTM_Destination_ID = PITM_Source_ID
    and POTM_Status_ID = 30)
```

In the where clause, there are some commented lines where a left join is done based on a condition.

```
--and (
--(PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID != 145 AND PRMA_Purchase_Request_No *= PITM_Related_Request_No)
--OR ( PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145 AND PRDE_MR_No *= PITM_Related_Request_No) 
--)
```

I have updated some of the query as you can see in the `FROM` clause. But, I am unable to even begin to understand how to replicate this special condition in `FROM` clause. I am definitely not experienced enough to do this for sure.

Edit:

I guess, this might have created some confusion, as column names don't use any table alias. Anyway, first 4 letters of column names denote the table name they belong to. (Don't blame me, it is not my schema. It is some 20 year old code, just look at the query for proof).

Anyway Table names for the columns:

```
TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master -- PITM_Related_Request_No (All columns that start with PITM)
TBL_Purchase_Request_Details -- PRDE_MR_No (All columns that start with PRDE)
TBL_Purchase_Request_Master -- PRMA_Purchase_Request_No (All columns that start with PRMA)
```

Edit:

Adding the original query before I modified it.

```
SELECT
         PRDE_Parts_Spec_ID
        ,PRDE_Service_Center_ID 
        ,ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(PRDE_Qty_Required,0)),0) - ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(PITM_Total_Qty_Received,0)),0)
FROM 
TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master
,TBL_Purchase_Request_Master
,TBL_Purchase_Request_Details

WHERE
    PRMA_Purchase_Request_No = PRDE_Purchase_Request_No 
    and PITM_Related_Request_Type_Id = 82 
    and PRDE_Parts_Spec_ID *= PITM_Parts_Spec_ID
    and PRDE_Service_Center_ID *= PITM_Service_Center_ID
    and PRDE_Required_Delivery_Date *= PITM_Expected_Arrival_Date
    and (
    (PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID != 145 AND PRMA_Purchase_Request_No *= PITM_Related_Request_No)
    OR ( PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145 AND PRDE_MR_No *= PITM_Related_Request_No) 
    )
    --and (PITM_status_id=25 or PITM_status_id=77 or PITM_status_id=81) 
    and not exists
    (SELECT POTM_Related_Txn_No 
    FROM TBL_Parts_Out_Txn_Master
    WHERE POTM_Related_Txn_No = PITM_Parts_In_Request_ID
    and POTM_Destination_Details = PITM_Source_Details
    and POTM_Destination_ID = PITM_Source_ID
    and POTM_Status_ID = 30) 
    AND PRMA_PR_Status_ID IN (41,146,213,9097) --PO Raised,Received,Invoiced,Partially received statuses
    AND PRMA_Supplier_ID = 0
    AND PRMA_Order_Date < @dtEndDate
```

Comment: First step is to work out what _tables_ the columns in these statements belong to: `PRMA_Purchase_Request_No *= PITM_Related_Request_No`, `PRDE_MR_No *= PITM_Related_Request_No`. Update your commented code to include table names. In fact if you are refactoring this code, you should alias the tables.

Comment: Don't be concerned, you can put any condition you want in an ON clause, that's what you will do here, once you have worked out which tables are being joined.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what version of SQL Server are you running this on? I thought all versions since 2005 had deprecated and didn't accept the old style joins.

Comment: you can use a setting to allow * = = *  ,think it still exists to this day (have forgotten what the setting name is though)

Comment: dude, just give up SQL..you would be much better off using R or Python if you have a query that contains so much logic .

Comment: yeah, if only. It is a production software of one of the fortune 500 company (25+ year old code), which has seen 10+ upgrades over the years. Rewriting from scratch was my suggestion, but client turned it down. :/    

@jpw sql server 2014. and this operator being deprecated is the whole reason of upgrading. I wouldn't touch that bad a schema otherwise. There is a reason, the company who wrote the code said no for the upgrade, causing my client to look for us.

Comment: er.... use Python instead of SQL?

Comment: can't use python. it is a part of 1500 line stored procedure, not a query written by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised after showing original query:

I am not convinced there is a surviving `OUTER JOIN` after seeing the original query, there are filtering conditions in the where clause that appear to negate the left join making it into an implicit inner join. In particular the `NOT EXISTS` condition which is entirely dependent on the existence of field values from the (so called) left joined table.

I also cannot see logic where there are 2 OR's

So, I would try this first, simply using an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
      PRDE.PRDE_Parts_Spec_ID
    , PRDE.PRDE_Service_Center_ID
    , ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(PRDE.PRDE_Qty_Required, 0)), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(PITM.PITM_Total_Qty_Received, 0)), 0)
FROM TBL_Purchase_Request_Master PRMA
      INNER JOIN TBL_Purchase_Request_Details PRDE
                  ON PRMA.PRMA_Purchase_Request_No = PRDE.PRDE_Purchase_Request_No
      INNER JOIN TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master PITM
                  ON PRDE.PRDE_Parts_Spec_ID = PITM.PITM_Parts_Spec_ID
                        AND PRDE.PRDE_Service_Center_ID = PITM.PITM_Service_Center_ID
                        AND PRDE.PRDE_Required_Delivery_Date = PITM.PITM_Expected_Arrival_Date
                        AND (
                              (PRMA.PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID != 145
                                AND PRMA.PRMA_Purchase_Request_No = PITM.PITM_Related_Request_No)
                          OR 
                              (PRMA.PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145 
                                AND PRDE.PRDE_MR_No = PITM.PITM_Related_Request_No)
                            )
WHERE PRMA.PRMA_PR_Status_ID IN (41, 146, 213, 9097) --PO Raised,Received,Invoiced,Partially received statuses
      AND PRMA.PRMA_Supplier_ID = 0
      AND PRMA.PRMA_Order_Date < @dtEndDate
      AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  POTM_Related_Txn_No
            FROM TBL_Parts_Out_Txn_Master
            WHERE POTM_Related_Txn_No = PITM.PITM_Parts_In_Request_ID
                  AND POTM_Destination_Details = PITM.PITM_Source_Details
                  AND POTM_Destination_ID = PITM.PITM_Source_ID
                  AND POTM_Status_ID = 30
      )
      AND PITM.PITM_Related_Request_Type_Id = 82
;
```

**IF** there is an effective `OUTER JOIN` then I believe it would be like this:

```
SELECT
      PRDE.PRDE_Parts_Spec_ID
    , PRDE.PRDE_Service_Center_ID
    , ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(PRDE.PRDE_Qty_Required, 0)), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(PITM.PITM_Total_Qty_Received, 0)), 0)
FROM TBL_Purchase_Request_Master PRMA
      INNER JOIN TBL_Purchase_Request_Details PRDE
                  ON PRMA.PRMA_Purchase_Request_No = PRDE.PRDE_Purchase_Request_No
      LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master PITM
                  ON PRDE.PRDE_Parts_Spec_ID = PITM.PITM_Parts_Spec_ID
                        AND PRDE.PRDE_Service_Center_ID = PITM.PITM_Service_Center_ID
                        AND PRDE.PRDE_Required_Delivery_Date = PITM.PITM_Expected_Arrival_Date
                        AND (
                        (PRMA.PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID != 145 AND PRMA.PRMA_Purchase_Request_No = PITM.PITM_Related_Request_No)
                        OR (PRMA.PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145 AND PRDE.PRDE_MR_No = PITM.PITM_Related_Request_No)
                        )
                        AND PITM.PITM_Related_Request_Type_Id = 82
 WHERE PRMA.PRMA_PR_Status_ID IN (41, 146, 213, 9097) --PO Raised,Received,Invoiced,Partially received statuses
      AND PRMA.PRMA_Supplier_ID = 0
      AND PRMA.PRMA_Order_Date < @dtEndDate
      AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  POTM_Related_Txn_No
            FROM TBL_Parts_Out_Txn_Master
            WHERE POTM_Related_Txn_No = PITM.PITM_Parts_In_Request_ID
                  AND POTM_Destination_Details = PITM.PITM_Source_Details
                  AND POTM_Destination_ID = PITM.PITM_Source_ID
                  AND POTM_Status_ID = 30
      )
;
```

---

It seems the field naming convention includes a reference to the table it belongs to (e.g. **PRDE** is an abbreviation of **P**urchase **R**equest **DE**tails) so while aliases aren't being used it is possible to deduce what tables each field is referring to.

I have nonetheless introduced aliases, if you don't want them they may be removed.

Comment: It does a left join on different tables based on the condition, which is the whole cause of confusion. `PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145` if this condition is true, we need to do left join on PRDE table, and otherwise on PRMA table.

So, we can either do a full outer join and use this condition, or use sub queries instead. Not sure, which one will work better though, or will be more sensible approach.

Comment: BTW, I tried your query. It gave me 20% rows than normal, and took 5 times as much time. :/

Comment: New attempt after seeing the original, but it doesn't have the GROUP BY clause which it clearly needs.

Comment: Great. Second query works. Although, I don't understand how `PRMA.PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145 AND PRDE.PRDE_MR_No = PITM.PITM_Related_Request_No` works. I will keep on looking at your query to understand how the joins are happening. But, for now, it works wonderfully, and that means I can leave early today. 

Thanks a lot, for saving my friday night. I will buy you a drink, sometime, if we ever meet up. :)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for getting back to me. I wasn't utterly sure about the inner join but thought it was worth trying. Branching in a join isn't very common but it isn't rare either, it simply means you join with combination (X=Y and A=B) OR with combination (Y=Z and C=D) its really no different in logic to filtering with ORs

Comment: Yeah, I understood that part. Although, I don't understand how SQL server handles the request. Does it do a cross join and filter in this case? Or does it do two separate filters, and then combine the results? I guess, I will keep trying to understand it.

Comment: I would expect: two separate filters, and then combine the results. Have no idea why you suggest a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated info we can convert the commented out join to this:

```
and (
   (
    PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID != 145 AND 
    TBL_Purchase_Request_Master.PRMA_Purchase_Request_No 
    *= 
    TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master.PITM_Related_Request_No
   )
   OR 
   (
    PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145 AND 
    TBL_Purchase_Request_Details.PRDE_MR_No 
    *= 
    TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master.PITM_Related_Request_No
   ) 
)
```

This means we need a left outer join between

1. `TBL_Purchase_Request_Master` and `TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master`
2. `TBL_Purchase_Request_Details` and `TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master`

You have already defined the first one in your existing FROM clause. You just have to add the condition to it. It doesn't make sense to AND it so try an OR:

So I *think* your FROM should be like this (but it is very difficult to work out without seeing the data model)

```
FROM 
TBL_Purchase_Request_Details 
Inner Join 
TBL_Purchase_Request_Master 
ON PRMA_Purchase_Request_No = PRDE_Purchase_Request_No 
Left Join 
TBL_Parts_In_Txn_Master M
ON (
     ( 
     M.PRDE_Parts_Spec_ID = PITM_Parts_Spec_ID AND 
     M.PRDE_Service_Center_ID = PITM_Service_Center_ID AND 
     M.PRDE_Required_Delivery_Date = PITM_Expected_Arrival_Date 
     )
     OR
     (
     TBL_Purchase_Request_Master.PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID != 145 AND 
     TBL_Purchase_Request_Master.PRMA_Purchase_Request_No = M.PITM_Related_Request_No
     )
 OR
 (
     TBL_Purchase_Request_Master.PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145 AND 
     TBL_Purchase_Request_Details.PRDE_MR_No = M.PITM_Related_Request_No
     )
```

I know it's annoying working with old code but it's worth keeping in mind that if it's a complex transformation, the code to transform it is going to be complicated. Would you rather have a bunch of different views pieced together (each of which you can unit test), or one HUMUNGOUS SQL statement representing all of those views in one go? Often stuff is built this way under tight constraints too. Managers are not interested in doing things properly, only coders are, but we don't pull the strings.

Comment: I know all about old code. Just see my history, and you will see. :/

Anyway, I didn't know I can add conditions like `TBL_Purchase_Request_Master.PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145` in the From clause. This might work easily then. Although, if you see the commented part again, you will see the left join is done on different tables based on the `TBL_Purchase_Request_Master.PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145` condition. If it is true, we need to left join PRDE table, and otherwise, left join PRMA table. 

What about full outer join, and then using this condition in where clause?

Comment: My gut feel is that you should not be using a full outer join but it's difficult for me to visualise.

Comment: I know, I shouldn't. But, I have to somehow recreate this whole query, so whatever it takes, I guess. Anyway, I am trying sub query right now, and till now, no luck.

Comment: If the business logic requires you to do a FULL OUTER JOIN you should, if it doesn't then don't. I'm sorry to say that I don't have enough brain power right now to analyse this any further but hopefully the info about what can go into an `ON` clause will help.

Comment: Can I suggest you get a piece of paper and draw the table and hsw they are meant to be joined with a crowsfeet diagram and go from there. It might help

Comment: That's the thing. I am unable to understand the whole join process itself. How is this condition `PRMA_Purchase_Request_Type_ID = 145 AND PRDE_MR_No *= PITM_Related_Request_No` supposed to be represented. First part is from a different table, then the one join is performed on. 

Right now, all I feel I can do is do a full outer join on all 3, then use conditions to select rows. But, even that is difficult as *= can't be replaced by anything in a where clause. It can only be replaced by a join clause. I tried sub-query, unions of two queries, but both failed. :/